# Awesome WM eof expected near end

Tags: awesome

I'm trying to add the network usage widget shown in the Awesome wiki but I'm running into an error. Here is the code:

```
     -- Create the wibox
 mywibox[s] = awful.wibox({ position = "top", screen = s })
 -- Add widgets to the wibox - order matters
 mywibox[s].widgets = {
     {
         mylauncher,
         mytaglist[s],
         mypromptbox[s],
         layout = awful.widget.layout.horizontal.leftright
     },
     mylayoutbox[s],
     mytextclock,
     netwidget,       --   ADD THIS, don't forget the comma!
     s == 1 and mysystray or nil,
     mytasklist[s],
     layout = awful.widget.layout.horizontal.rightleft
   }
end
-- }}}
```

The error I'm getting says " expected near 'end'". I assume they mean the 'end' in the code here, as it's red in my rc.lua file, but I can't figure out what I should do with it.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't the the "end" syntax in the end of your lua script. Just remove it.

It's for something like "if", "functions" and "for" loops.

References:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993973/eof-expected-neard-end
- http://www.lua.org/pil/contents.html